# Modified structs allocated in memory do not retain values after end of function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a couple of structs: A HashTable, which contains a table of pointers to WordNodes, and each WordNode contains a pointer to a List, which is a linked list made up of ListNodes.

I wrote a function to create a list and add list nodes to a WordNode:

```
int addWord(char* word, HashTable* hash_table, int id)
{
  WordNode* current = calloc(1, sizeof(WordNode));
  current = hash_table->table[hash];

  // ...

  if(current->docs == NULL){
    // Create a new list, and initialize it
    List* list = calloc(1, sizeof(List));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;

    int occur = 1;
    ListNode* list_node = AddNode(list); // Create the first node in the list

    current->docs = list;                // Link the WordNode to the list

    // Fill in relevant details of ListNode
    list_node->id= &id;    
    list_node->occurrences = &occur;
    list_node->next = NULL;
```

That is my function, but since it's been giving me trouble, I added a couple of lines inside it to test it:

```
    printf("Testing:\n");
    WordNode* wnode = calloc(1, sizeof(WordNode));
    wnode = hash_table->table[hash];

    List* my_list = calloc(1, sizeof(List));
    my_list = wnode->docs;

    ListNode* dnode = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
    dnode = my_list->head;

    printf("Results: ocurrences: %d, id: %d\n",*((int*)dnode->occurrences),
      *((int*)dnode->id));
    printf("The dnode is %d\n", doc_node);

}
```

When called in main, the testing code inside the function produces the expected output:

```
Results: ocurrences: 1, id: 15
The dnode is 13867424
```

However, the same testing in the line immediately following the function call in main produces a weird output, even though the pointer seems to be pointing to the same address.

```
Results: ocurrences: 0, id: 54
The dnode is 13867424
```

Possibly relevant code from the function that adds a new node to the list:

```
ListNode* AddNode(List * list)
{

  ListNode* node = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
  node->next = NULL;

  if(list->tail == NULL){
      list->head = node;
      list->tail = node;
  }
  else{
      list->tail->next = node;
      list->tail = node;
  }

  return node;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. It would seem to me that I am somehow handling the structs as local variables, even though I am allocating memory for them, which makes me think they shouldn't change after the function is done. It is probably a C-programmer's beginner mistake, but I can't seem to figure out where I am getting this wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.  An important part of an MCVE would be the structure definitions.  Another would be the data that you're using to create the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One set of problems is in the code:

```
int addWord(char* word, HashTable* hash_table, int id)
{
    …omitted…

    int occur = 1;
    ListNode* list_node = AddNode(list); // Create the first node in the list

    current->docs = list;                // Link the WordNode to the list

    // Fill in relevant details of ListNode
    list_node->id= &id;    
    list_node->occurrences = &occur;
```

You're storing a pointer to a parameter and a pointer to a local variable in your structure.  Dereferencing either of those after the function returns is undefined behaviour.  The space occupied by those could be reused by the compiler for any purpose at any time; they could become completely invalid (but probably won't).

Why do you have pointers in your structure for those two items?  Surely, the structure should just contain a couple of `int` members, not `int *` members!

If, perchance, your code is compiling with warnings, don't submit it to SO; fix the warnings first.  Or seek help on how to resolve the compiler warnings.  They all matter.  At this stage in your career, remember that the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.  If it warns about something in your code, the compiler is probably correct to be worried and the code is probably incorrect in some way.

Your code doesn't show where `word` is used — it could be that you are not copying that data either.